# Is this legal in C++?

Tags: c++, c, c++-cli

I created a C++/CLI wrapper calling a third party code, which happened to end in corrupted memory. So I'm suspecting that maybe the code wasn't legal in C++

below is the code that crashed:

```
void Init_4bit_tab(unsigned char *dest,unsigned char *source)
        {
            unsigned char masque,i;

            masque=0x08;
            for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
                dest[i] = (*source & masque)>>(3-i);
                masque >>= 1;
            }
        }
```

the exact error was:
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Update:

After scanning the 3rd party code, It appears to be multidimensional array, because of the way it was passed, but I'm still not sure what's causing the problem:

the source function

```
unsigned char Data_B[81];
...
S_Box_Calc(&Data_B[33]);

void S_Box_Calc(unsigned char *vect)
        {
              unsigned char *S_Box[8];
              unsigned lig,col,i;

              S_Box[0]=S1;
              S_Box[1]=S2;
              S_Box[2]=S3;
              S_Box[3]=S4;
              S_Box[4]=S5;
              S_Box[5]=S6;
              S_Box[6]=S7;
              S_Box[7]=S8;

              for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
                    col= 8*vect[1+6*i] + 4*vect[2+6*i] + 2*vect[3+6*i] + vect[4+6*i];
                    lig= 2*vect[6*i] + vect[5+6*i];
                    Init_4bit_tab(&vect[4*i],&S_Box[i][col+lig*16]);
              }
        }
```

Update 2:
I checked the values on debug mode the dest and source are not null. however if I tried to quick watch (*source & masque) under this code dest[i] = (*source & masque)>>(3-i);

I get this error

(*source & masque)  error: & cannot be performed on '*source' and 'masque'

Update 3:
S1...Sn was originally defined on the global scope of the file, but I get an error when I left it as is, so I initialized them in the constructor this way:

```
unsigned char lS1[64] = { 
                14,4,13,1,2,15,11,8,3,10,6,12,5,9,0,7,
                0,15,7,4,14,2,13,1,10,6,12,11,9,5,3,8,
                4,1,14,8,13,6,2,11,15,12,9,7,3,10,5,0,
                15,12,8,2,4,9,1,7,5,11,3,14,10,0,6,13
            };
            std::copy(S1, S1 + 64, lS1);
```

could this be the problem?

Comment: sounds like the memory pointed to by `dest` is not valid/large enough.

Comment: source=nullptr would also cause the crash

Comment: What is the declaration/definition of `S1`, `S2`, etc.?

Comment: @legends2k S1, S2 contains array of unsigned char, unsigned char S1[64]

Comment: @user2817517 And what is the content of `Data_B`?  In this code, `vect` is both an in and an out variable, and the indices into the `Sn` are calculated based on its contents.  (The code looks fishy to me: it steps through reading `vect` with a step of 6, and writing it with a step of `4`.  But without more context, who knows?)

Comment: Re your last edit: not null doesn't mean that a pointer is valid.  And the "error" you're getting comes from where?  Given the data declarations, the expression is certainly legal.

Comment: The only I can imagine is: vec is not holding 0 or 1, only. Eg. '0' or '1' would be fatal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with the code you show, *if* it is passed
valid pointers.  If it's corrupting memory, it's probably
because the caller didn't pass it valid pointers.

After your edit: if `S_Box_Calc` is called with `vect` equal to
`Data_B + 33`, as you show, the range `[vect, vect+48)` is
legal, which means that `Init_4bit_tab` should not be called
with a value superior to 44.  In fact, in the code you show, it
is never called with a value greater than 28, so you shouldn't be able
to corrupt memory here.  If any of `S1` through `S8`, however, do
not point to valid memory, you'll get the symptoms you state.

Comment: as of edit 3, I tried looking at the constructor, after std::copy the lSn wasn't copied correctly to Sn, instead they all became 0xcd characters

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly legal C++ syntactically, it compiles. Check if it's semantically correct. The only place where you could inadvertently tread in the UB land is in accessing `dest` pointer i.e. The array it is pointing to should atleast be 4 chars long from where it's pointing to. Also since the error talks about access violation, make sure `dest` is pointing to a writable memory location.

Comment: "Legal C++" != "Compiling C++". "Undefined behavior" is what happens when you have an illegal program that doesn't violate any of the rules the compiler can detect.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: From C++ standard: `In C++, the static or extern specifiers can only be applied to names of objects or functions.
Using these specifiers with type declarations is _illegal_ in C++` i.e. the compiler throws an error.

Comment: Illegal simply means that it's invalid by the language grammar. So `undefined behaviour` cannot happen if it's invalid since it'd have never compiled in the first place.

Comment: Illegal doesn't actually mean anything. This is the only use of "illegal" in the standard, and it's in the non-normative appendix C.

Comment: @legends2k What makes you say that.  The term for a program which is invalid by the language grammar is ill formed.  Ill formed programs are illegal, but they're not the only programs which are illegal.  There are rules for which no diagnostic is required.

Comment: My point was legality has nothing to do with behaviour. "cows flow supremely" is grammatically ok (subject verb adverb) in English, but makes no sense.

Comment: @SebastianRedl "Illegal" does have a more general signification.  About the same as when the standard speaks of "violation or a rule".  As in the second paragraph of section 1.4, in which the standard divides programs into three groups: those which contain no violations of the rules, those which contain a violation of a diagnosable rule, and those which contain a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic is required.

Comment: @legends2k The standard says otherwise, and very definitely
places requirements on a program beyond simple syntactical
correctness.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I stand corrected. Ill-formed is a better word. And I also see that Stroustrup, in his C++11 FAQ mentions, reading from an enum member which was not written to is _illegal_.

Comment: @legends2k the compiler is complaining it couldn't perform '&' operation for the ff line (*source & masque)

Comment: @user2817517 I rather doubt that.  The operation is legal.  (Provided, of course, that `source` points to valid memory.  But the compiler cannot know whether that will be the case at runtime, and so cannot complain.  Look at the values of `source` and `dest` in the debugger.)

Comment: @JamesKanze You're right, I checked again and it says in english that the value is 0x07389EB0 <undefined value>.

Answer (score 0):

Where are your overflow checks?  You should be passing in sizes to your functions to allow you to restrict writes to memory if there is a chance that it will overflow.  It's similar to strcpy() vs. strncpy() or strlcpy() in BSD.  Perhaps if you implement something along those lines and generate an error where there is a condition that memory written would otherwise overflow, you might find the cause of memory corruption.